# Muenchian grouping for BizTalk mapping

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk, biztalk-2013, muenchian-grouping

I have two input schemas one for member and one for benefits. Each Member can have 1 to n number of benefits. Member and Benefits has employee ID field. So I need to map both the views in to output schema. The output schema looks like below

[image]

As I want the output like

```
 MEMBER,1,134,134,Jo, ,Arch,1,S,M
 BENEFIT,1,M,1,89,7,1,1,20110101,20120731,11
 BENEFIT,1,D,2,89,3,11,5,20110101,20120731,16
 MEMBER,14,448,448,Cli,M,Ast,1,M,M
 BENEFIT,14,D,2,89,3,11,5,20170101,17000101,16
 BENEFIT,14,M,1,89,7,1,1,20170101,17000101,11
 BENEFIT,14,M,1,89,7,1,1,20150101,20161231,11
 MEMBER,15,332,332,Ash,,Cox,1,M,M
 BENEFIT,15,D,2,89,3,11,5,20170101,17000101,16
```

Below is the map I am using to check the Employee_ID of both the views and mapping them the values in to the Benefit elements like below

[image]

But with this map I am getting the response like below

```
MEMBER,1,134,134,Jo, ,Arch,1,S,M
MEMBER,14,448,448,Cli,M,Ast,1,M,M
MEMBER,15,332,332,Ash,,Cox,1,M,M
BENEFIT,1,M,1,89,7,1,1,20110101,20120731,11
BENEFIT,1,D,2,89,3,11,5,20110101,20120731,16
```

Just list of Member and the Benefit of the 1st member. How can I fix this to have the Member and their benefit then again Member and their benefit.Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You tag `xslt` and one of its methods `muenchian-grouping` but show us *mapping* diagrams. What answer do you expect us to give? If only `biztalk`, please remove other tags.

Comment: You can't do proper Munechian grouping using the BizTalk mapping designer.  You'll need to rewrite your map as custom XSLT.  I wrote a blog surveying some methods on this a while back https://blog.tallan.com/2014/12/09/muenchian-grouping-in-biztalk-while-keeping-mapper-functionality/

Comment: Following [this guide](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2009/10/28/biztalk-training-mapping-muenchian-grouping-and-sorting-in-biztalk-maps-without-losing-map-functionalities/) worked fine for me. You can maybe give us your xslt code..